# Override class-level ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true) on method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller which I declare, at class level, to not show up in the autogenerated API Help Page, like so:

```
[Authorize, ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class MyController : ApiController {
    public HttpResponseMessage method1() {/*...*/}
    public HttpResponseMessage method2() {/*...*/}
    public HttpResponseMessage method3() {/*...*/}
    /*...*/
}
```

Now say I want to override the `ApiExplorerSettings` annotation just for `method2` in order to add it to the docs. I obviously tried:

```
[Authorize, ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class MyController : ApiController {
    public HttpResponseMessage method1() {/*...*/}
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
    public HttpResponseMessage method2() {/*...*/}
    public HttpResponseMessage method3() {/*...*/}
    /*...*/
}
```

but to no avail. Any insight as to how I could achieve this behavior?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swashbuckle to generate your API help page, you can configure SwaggerGen with a DocumentFilter. The filter allows you to programmatically modify the SwaggerDocument, (i.e. add or remove some methods) before it is made available to SwaggerUI.

Some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701573/how-to-omit-methods-from-swagger-documentation-on-webapi-using-swashbuckle)