# ASP.Net Core + Swagger - Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have a project *MyProject.Api* with following structure:

```
Controllers/
- Api/
  - UsersController.cs
- HomeController.cs
Startup.cs
```

where **HomeController.cs** looks like this:

```cs
namespace MyProject.Api.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv) {...}

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {...}

        [HttpGet("sitemap.xml")]
        public IActionResult SiteMap() {...}

        [HttpGet("error")]
        public IActionResult Error() {...}
    }
}
```

and **UsersController.cs** looks like this:

```cs
namespace MyProject.Api.Controllers.Api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApiHelper<UsersController> _apiHelper;
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public UsersController(ILogger<UsersController> logger, IUserService userService) {...}

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Login([FromBody] LoginRequest request) {...}

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterRequest request) {...}

        [HttpGet("renew")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Renew() {...}
    }
}
```

and **Startup.cs**:

```cs
namespace MyProjet.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {...}

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info {Title = "Web Api Docs", Version = "v1"}));
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            ...

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1"); });
            app.MapWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/swagger", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), builder =>
            {
                builder.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                       "spa-fallback",
                        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

when I load `/swagger` the UI loads successfully, but with following error:

```
Fetch error
Internal Server Error /swagger/v1/swagger.json
```

and with this error on the server side

```cs
System.NotSupportedException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - WebEssentials.AspNetCore.Pwa.PwaController.ServiceWorkerAsync (WebEssentials.AspNetCore.Pwa). Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger 2.0
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItem(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, ISchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String documentName, String host, String basePath, String[] schemes)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

but all methods have unique route, unique name and their HTTP methods are explicitly bound. I've tried adding `[Route("")]` to the *HomeController.cs*, but that did not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The stack trace states that the method at `WebEssentials.AspNetCore.Pwa.PwaController.ServiceWorkerAsync` requires an explicit HttpMethod binding. Unfortunately for you that controller is in a third party library. So you're best option to get around that is to not use that library

Comment: @devNull I must be blind! Thank you!

Comment: I solved the same issue by adding  [HttpGet] to the related Action.

Comment: 1-remove parameters from Http??? and let it [Http???]
2-add [Route] attribute and add routing parameters to it and it should work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [@devNull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5803406/devnull) said, the mistake is not in my code but in `WebEssentials.AspNetCore.Pwa.PwaController.ServiceWorkerAsync`.

**UPDATE:**

My pull [request](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker/pull/62) with fix (Added explicit HttpMethod bindings) was now merged to [WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker/) repository and will hopefully be available in next release on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA/) with version **newer** than *1.0.59*

**OLD SOLUTION:**

I found the following solution posted [here](https://github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-angular-universal/issues/656#issuecomment-397927589) by [Gandii](https://github.com/Gandii).

1. Create somewhere class **ApiExplorerIgnores** with following content

```cs
public class ApiExplorerIgnores : IActionModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        if (action.Controller.ControllerName.Equals("Pwa"))
            action.ApiExplorer.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

2. Add following code to method **ConfigureServices** in **Startup.cs**

```cs
services.AddMvc(c => c.Conventions.Add(new ApiExplorerIgnores()))
```

This should hide the **PwaController** from *ApiExplorer* which is used by *Swashbuckle*.

Comment: Not included in 1.0.59, I just ran into this issue. The "old" solution worked for me though.

Comment: I just addded [HttpGet] on method and it works fine.
Environment .Net Core 3.1 with SwashBuckle 5.1

Comment: Now you could add `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` to ignore Swagger from including the controller from the documentation. This also help prevent this issue.

Answer (score 21):

Had the same error but without any third party library involved.

Problem in my code was, that there where `public` methods in my controller base class being used by the controller but not to be exposed by the controller.

Example:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : GenericController<TestClass>
{
    public TestController() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class GenericController<T1>
{
    public GenericController()
    {
    // ...
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<T1>>> Get()
    {
    // ...
    }
    
    public void DoStuff()
    {
    // ...
    }
}
```

Changing the access modifier of `DoStuff`  to `internal` solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

my issue was there was no [HttpGet] above my method for it to actually get the api that i wanted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

Swagger (at least v3.0 and below) will fail if Http action method has a parameter. So, use [HttpPost] instead of [HttpPost("somename")].

Answer (score 4):

Had the same error but it was different solution. When merging master to my branch, I deleted [HttpGet] in my controller above the function that was written in the debug console. Hope that my experience helps someone

Answer (score 0):

For me, the controller action reported in the error didn't have any HTTP verb decorator. I added it and it worked.
Error was

> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Ambiguous
> HTTP method for action xxxxxx.ErrorController.Error

**Earlier Code**

```
[Route("error/{code}", Name = "ErrorByCode")]
        public IActionResult Error(int code)
        {
            var err = ErrResp.GetErrorObject(code.ToString());
            return new ObjectResult(err);
        }
```

**Fix**

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("error/{code}", Name = "ErrorByCode")]
        public IActionResult Error(int code)
        {
            var err = ErrResp.GetErrorObject(code.ToString());
            return new ObjectResult(err);
        }
```

Please note, `[HttpGet]` HTTP verb decorator added.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you have a public method in a controller which you can't make internal (see [sc911's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64571000/1294318)), an alternative is to decorate the method so the API Explorer [ignores it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701573/how-to-omit-methods-from-swagger-documentation-on-webapi-using-swashbuckle):

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, I would also suggest checking all the new routes and endpoints added in the new commit, that was in my case

Comment: This does not provide a new answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35117635)