# Exclude particular Web Api endpoint from the swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, webapi

I'm using Swagger UI with asp.net core web api. For my `CRUD` operations, I have a base controller class, which defines abstract methods:

```
public class BaseController<TDto, TEntity>
{
    [HttpPost, Route("create-single")]
    public abstract Task<ObjectResult> CreateAsync(TDto input);

    [HttpPost, Route("create-many")]
    public abstract Task<ObjectResult> CreateManyAsync(IList<TDto> input);

    [HttpGet, Route("get-all")]
    public abstract Task<ObjectResult> GetAllAsync();

    [HttpGet, Route("get/{id}")]
    public abstract Task<ObjectResult> GetByIdAsync(Guid id);

    ...
    ...
}
```

Some controller might not need all the CRUD methods, and I need to disappear those endpoints from the swagger.

For example, I need to disappear `/get/{id}` endpoint for particular controller, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Better question is why making routes generic, each resource should have its own handling

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add the following attribute to Controllers and Actions to exclude them from the generated documentation: **[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]**

Comment: My controller action produces 4 endpoints (due to 2 optional url arguments). What if I want to keep only the first without the 2 optional arguments and remove the rest?

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis you would need a filter for this. Take a look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54788867/2343336