# Get error swagger when change method private to public

Tags: c#, swagger

This is my code in UserController and it runs well.

```
private Identifier GetCurrentUser()
        {
            var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (identity != null)
            {
                var userClaims = identity.Claims;
                return new Identifier
                {
                    Id = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value,
                    Role = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value,
                };
            }
            return null;
        }
```

[image]
However when I change this method from private to public I got this error with swagger.
[image]
I do not understand why I get this error. Please tell me the reason and teach me how to fix it. Thank for your attention

Comment: can you post the full controller?

Comment: This is my userController: https://github.com/psawn/Sem3Project/blob/main/BE/Sem3Project/Controllers/UserController.cs

Comment: maybe you need this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701573/how-to-omit-methods-from-swagger-documentation-on-webapi-using-swashbuckle

Comment: public methods in a controller are automatically interpreted as endpoints and the swagger request fails, because with that extra endpoint you have conflicting routes --> multiple endpoints exist on the same route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it has been pointed out in the comment, you have conflicting route names with api/GetUsers/{search} and api/GetUsers/{id}. It becomes difficult for the compiler to figure out which one you really want to use.

I recommend you change the GetUserById action method to this form so there's a distinction between the two routes.

```
[HttpGet("\GetUser\{id}")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,Staff")]
public IActionResult GetUser(string id)
```

Alternatively you could place the `search` term for GetUsers in the same class as the `paginationFilter` like this

```
public class SearchAndPagination
{
    public PaginationFilter paginationFilter {get;set;}
    public string search {get;set;}
}
```

Then pass as request body to GetUsers action

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,Staff")]
public IActionResult GetUsers([FromBody] SearchAndPagination paginationFilter)
{
    var users = _userRepository.GetUsers(paginationFilter.paginationFilter, paginationFilter.search);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a public method in the controller, where the library I used requires only public methods, and swagger was not happy with that because could not figure out is that endpoint or not.
I have to decorate the public method with NonAction annotation like below code. It solved the problem

```
  [NonAction]
  public void SendEmail(string text)
  { 
  }
```