# Asp.net Core + Swagger : How to show APIs of type GET

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

How can I show only APIs of type GET in Swagger page and hide others?
I found that the attribute `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`
can hide the API from Swagger page,
 but I have lot of APIs to hide and I need an approach to hide the APIs depending on its HTTP type.
I've tried this approach :

```
 public class SwaggerFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            var nonGetPaths = swaggerDoc.Paths.Where(x => x.Value.Operations.First().Key != OperationType.Get);
            var count=nonGetPaths.Count();
            foreach (var item in nonGetPaths)
            {
                swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(item.Key);
            }
        }
    }
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe there is an answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701573/how-to-omit-methods-from-swagger-documentation-on-webapi-using-swashbuckle

Comment: I've checked this link before, but unfortunately I don't have convention in API naming, so I can't remove APIs by the name @mohi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a custom filter like this:

```
public class SwaggerFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        
        foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
        {
          foreach (var key in path.Value.Operations.Keys )
          {
            if (key != OperationType.Get)
            {
                swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(path.Key);
            }
          }
       }
       
    }
}
```

Then configure in program.cs(.Net 6)

```
//.......
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(x=>x.DocumentFilter<SwaggerFilter>());
//......
```

I don't add `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` in my apicontroller and it works all fine.

But, Make sure `Get` endpoint and other type of endpoint have different route in the same controller, You can add attribute route like `[HttpGet("/get")]` on  `Get` endpoint. If you just write like this in the same controller:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post()
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
```

`Get` and `Post` endpoint will have the same path. `swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(xxx);` will remove all of them.

**Reuslt:**

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: that was the solution, thanks