# How to exclude certain action from Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have a BaseController that defines an action method this way:

```
    [HttpGet("Duplicate/{dup}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DuplicateAsync(string dup)
    {
        if (DuplicateIdRegEx().IsMatch(dup))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(dup.AsSpan(1), out int id))
                return await EditAsync(id, true);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

That BaseController is the base class of all other controllers.

When I run Swagger, it parses every route, and since the Duplicate action is repeteated for all of the inherited controllers, Swagger is not run, throwing an exception.

How can I avoid Swagger parser to parse that action route?

Comment: decorating your action with [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]   ?  https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#omit-arbitrary-operations

Comment: Have you checked ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42235291/5433590

Comment: It works fine in my project. It is better for you to share the exception with us.

Comment: @Rena it is: `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "GET Edit/{id}" for actions - Modules.Authenticate.UI.Controllers.ReportController.EditAsync (Modules.Authenticate.UI),EntryPortal.UI.Controllers.TableroController.EditAsync (EntryPortal.UI). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. `. However, @Mate solution works.

Comment: @Mate It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try decorating your action with  `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
[HttpGet("Duplicate/{dup}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DuplicateAsync(string dup)
{
 ...
```

[Doc Official](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#omit-arbitrary-operations)